# Symfony2 - Custom ROLES

Tags: symfony, roles

I am trying to set custom roles to my security.yml, thus after the login the user can or can't access to the main page (I use ActiveDirectory).

All I want is to create one role: ROLE_GUEST

Here's my security.yml file :

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_GUEST:       ROLE_GUEST
    ROLE_USER:        [ROLE_GUEST, ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_GUEST, ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_GUEST, ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]
```

If I understood well, this is how I read those roles :

- A user who has the role 'ROLE_GUEST' can only see page which requires 'ROLE_GUEST'
- A user who has the role 'ROLE_USER' may also see any page which requires 'ROLE_GUEST'
- "A user who has the role 'ROLE_ADMIN' may also see any page which requires 'ROLE_GUEST' and 'ROLE_USER'"
- etc...

Then, I set the access_control as the following :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/$, role: ROLE_USER }
```

What I want in this access_control is to limit the access of the main page to only ROLE_USER. I already set the default role to ROLE_GUEST when the user logins for the first time. But even if I put ROLE_USER like above, I can access the main page with a user who has the ROLE_GUEST.

Any idea how I can get this working ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I figured it out.

Apparently the FOS User bundle automatically adds the ROLE "USER" to every users, even if you didn't say so in your User entity (you can check it on the profiler).

So by assuming you want a custom ROLE, keep in mind that `ROLE_USER` will always be the lower ROLE as everyone will have it.

Correct me if I'm wrong !

Oh also I've corrected my firewall and access_control (if it can help someone) :

Role Hierarchy settings:

```
role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_CUSTOM:     [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_CUSTOM]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN]
```

Firewalls settings :

```
firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
```

Access Control settings :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_CUSTOM } // IMPORTANT TO BE THE LAST ONE
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression seems to be the problem, `^/$` matches only one `/` and nothing else. This is what you mean I guess:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/.*, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Also your role hierarchy can be simplified:

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:        [ROLE_GUEST] # ROLE_USER implies ROLE_GUEST
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER] # ROLE_ADMIN implies ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN] # and so on ...
```

This page from the docs is very helpfull to understand the concept behind security voters:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html

In symfony 2.6 it is simplified to write custom voters: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-simpler-security-voters

And there is a video introduction on knpuniversities youtube channel:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fF8tpdlnyaE

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not what I want. As I said, I use ActiveDirectory, so every user can login. But I don't want everyone to have the same access, that's why I only want the USER to access the site and the ADMINs to access the site + ADMIN part.

Comment: Sorry, I totally ignored the active directory note... :P But your regular expression in the access_controll part might be the problem anyway I think. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Nope... I already had this REGEX problem once, and the only thing that works is `^/$`. Yours, `^/.*` does a redirection error. Also, When I set to the user ROLE_USER and I restrict the main page to ADMIN only, it does work: I get the 403 - Forbidden error. So I think it's more a problem of the custom role that anything else (I hope).

Comment: But `^/$` can't be what you really want, because it only matches a single slash or what am I missing again? Maybe the redirect problem is due to some other firewall configuration issue.

Comment: Mh, I'm not sure. I am aware that `^/.*$` would target all pages, but it doesn't work. The pattern setting under firewall is set to `^/`. I'm not sure if there's something to do with that. Also, why it does work when the ROLE of the user is "USER" and I restrict the page for the role "ADMIN" only ?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your user class doesn't have the ROLE_USER in the array of roles?

Comment: Yes I am sure. When I check the row it creates in the DB, I only have `a:1:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_GUEST";}`

Comment: Could it be that your `default_target_path` is behind the firewall? That would explain the redirect problem.

Comment: I am sure it's not. When I put `ROLE_GUEST` to the user by default and restrict the page to `ROLE_USER` and +, it does access this page. However, if I don't put a custom role to this user, for exemple if I put `ROLE_USER` by default and restrict the page to `ROLE_ADMIN`, the user doesn't get the access.